# Why are React props being rendered with HTML entities during server side rendering?

Tags: html, reactjs, encoding, rendering, server-side-rendering

This: `<a href="foo&bar">Test</a>`

Is being rendered as: `<a href="foo&amp;bar">Test</a>`

When using `ReactDOM.renderToString`

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/dijs/nf9khrej/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup()` to achieve your specific needs
I have created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/567wydsL/) for the same.